# Is there a performance hit for querying the file system in PHP?

Tags: php, performance

I was told many years ago that using "include" statements in PHP doesn't "cost" anything in performance. But what about when you query the file system, for instance running "filemtime" or "readdir". If I am performing these with every page request, is that a problem? Thanks!

Comment: Everything has a performance hit. If you need to query the filesystem, do it. How else are you going to get the information?

Comment: Use a [profiler](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler). It's usually negligible in comparison to database queries.

Comment: @Barmar - We could hardcode the results into the code, but that requires manual updating. Or could query the filesystem once and cache the data, but that would add a bit more complexity to the app.

Comment: reading the hard coded variable has a performance cost as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why include statements "don't cost anything" in performance, is because those include files are often cached as well. Semi compiled versions of PHP scripts can be stored in APC cache (See: http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)

Apart from that cache, the OS will also cache file access, so subsequent calls to `filemtime` won't need actual disk access every time. And even if the OS request information from the hard drive, that drive might have cached the most recent requests as well. So there is caching at multiple levels, all in order to make disk access as fast as possible.

So, for those reasons, calling `filemtime` many times should not be a big issue either, but if you need to read a lot of different files, the caches might not work optimally, and you will have a lot of actual disk I/O. Eventuall, if you have many visitor, the file I/O might become a bottleneck. You might be able to solve this by upgrading your hardware. A raid of SSDs will likely be able to read faster than a single spinning disk.

If performance is still an issue, you might store the filetime of a file in a cache yourself, for instance APC or memcache, or even an include file for PHP that contains an array of relevant file information. Of course you need to make sure to update this cache every time when you write a file. And make sure to profile every optimization you make. If you don't have APC, an include file probably won't do any good. Also, requests to memcache have some overhead even though the data itself is in memory. So these solutions are not guaranteed to improve things.

But as always, don't start implementing such optimizations if you don't need to. Premature optimization... :)

Comment: Thanks so much! My system is actually running Nginx, does that change anything?

Comment: It shouldn't matter much. I think Nginx is more memory-efficient when it comes to using PHP, but the way PHP accesses the disk should be the same.